# Need some help with C++ Trie data structures

Tags: c++, trie

I am trying to write a C++ function that matches whether a string is present in a dictionary . It can be a partial string or a complete string. SO I read each and every line into a trie

```
           trie< std::string, int > dict;
           dict.insert(make_pair(line,i++));
            // when i search for a string it always returns invalid.
           if(dict.find("AA")!=dict.end())
               cout<<valid<<endl;
           else
               cout<<invalid<<endl;
```

Can some one please help me with this. I added code for reading words in dictionary.

```
if(myfile.is_open())
{

      int i=0;
  string line;

      cout<<dict.size()<<endl;
      while(!myfile.eof())
  {
      getline(myfile,line);
      dict.insert(make_pair(line,i++));



  }
 }
```

Comment: this question is impossible to answer reasonably without knowing necessary declarations and variables

Comment: @aaa I used getline to read  a line and I checked the size of the dict and found it to be 179000. After using dict.find I check what it returns using it = dict.find("AA"); the value of (*it).second returns like 23880300

Comment: Homework? Anyway, the question is unanswerable - you should state clearly what you want. It seems to me you already have done what you want.

Comment: And what implementation of trie you are using.

Comment: @jpalecek. Nope this not home work. No one will ask to use GNU trie in a home work

Comment: @SCFrench its a GNU trie (patricia Trie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [this trie](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/trie_based_containers.html), [this sample code](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/ext/pb_ds/example/trie_prefix_search.cc) indicates you need more template parameters in your declaration to tell it how to split up the keys so it can do the trie indexing and especially prefix searches:

```
trie< std::string, int, string_trie_e_access_traits<>, pat_trie_tag, trie_prefix_search_node_update> dict;
```

Also note the use of `prefix_range` in the search function in the linked sample code.